# Hibernate: Already created table but another schema

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I want to create new table named BOOK using with hibernate.Our persistence.xml like this, and normally there are not any problem at all.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

But there is one another schema on same db that they have already created same named table (BOOK).So hibernate does not create new table.

How can I solve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide name of your schema and other schema ? If your schema is different from the one containing table BOOK then there won't be any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value to create,

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

This will create new database table,with schema of the same entity class everytime.

Later if you want to add records to the same table,again modify it to update.

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to drop existing datas.

Comment: ok.no issue...use @Table(name="new name"),give a new name to table in the entity class

Comment: You cannot have two tables with same names,in a single database

Comment: @volkan make sure you are not giving same table name which is already exsisting in the database